# Is it possible to get results from several database requests and merge them together?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i need to merge several snapshots together before i process the snapshot itself. Is it possible to get results from several database requests (snapshots) and merge them together, so they look like one snapshot ?
 I saw similar question here in Swift, but i would need to put this together in Javascript.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's nothing built in to the Firebase SDK for merging two snapshots. If you want something like that, you'll have to reimplement the snapshot yourself. While that is certainly possible, it is probably easier to come up with your own (smaller) interface, instead of the one from the database.